# VM Lamp Stack Magento Erro nas permissões?

Tags: magento, vagrant

Os problemas de permissões estão nessas pastas.

```
Path "/var/www/hf/app/etc" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/customer" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/dhl" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/xmlconnect" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/xmlconnect/original" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/xmlconnect/custom" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/xmlconnect/system" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/hf/media/downloadable" must be writable.
```

Porem eu procurei dar as permissões ao magento nas pastas especificadas e não está dando certo...

```
   class magento::magento {

    file { "/var/www/magento":
        ensure => "present",
        owner => "root",
        group => "root",
        mode => "0644",
        source => "puppet:///modules/magento/magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz",   
        require => Package["apache2", "mysql-server"],          
    }

    exec { "unzip-magento":     
        command => "tar -vzxf /var/www/magento",                
        path => "/bin/",
        require => File["/var/www/magento"],            
    }

    exec { "rename-dir-magento":
        command => "mv magento/ hf/",
        path => "/bin/",
        require => Exec["unzip-magento"],       
    }

    exec { "mv-hf":     
        command => 'mv hf/ /var/www/',
        path => "/bin/",
        require => Exec["rename-dir-magento"],  
        timeout => 90000,
        logoutput => on_failure,        

    }

    # a fuller example, including permissions and ownership
  file { ["/var/www/hf"]:
    ensure  => "directory",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0755",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }

    file { "/var/www/hf/var/":
    ensure  => "directory",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0777",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }

  file { "/var/www/hf/media":
    ensure  => "directory",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0777",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }

  file { "/var/www/hf/media":
    ensure  => "file",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0777",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }
    # permission for media and var directories
  file { ["/var/www/hf/var/cache", "/var/www/hf/var/locks", "/var/www/hf/var/package", "/var/www/hf/var/session"]:
    ensure  => "directory",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0667",
    recurse => "true",
    require => File["/var/www/hf/media", "/var/www/hf/var"],
  }

    # permission for media and var directories
  file { ["/var/www/hf/app/etc"]:
    ensure  => "directory",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0777",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }

  file { ["/var/www/hf/app/etc"]:
    ensure  => "file",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0777",
    recurse => "true",
    require => Exec["mv-hf"],
  }

}
```

Aqui está o código completo.: [repositorio Git](https://github.com/edesignerbrasil/VM-Lamp-Stack-Magento).
Se alguem conseguir me auxiliar pois em varias tentativas não consigo localizar meu erro.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui estão os passos seguidos:

– Setando permissões de todos diretórios parar 775

– Setando permissões de todos arquivos parar 644

– Setando permissões das pastas app/etc/, var/ e media/ e todos arquivos internos para 777

Basta somente executar o comando:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo chmod 777 -R app/etc/;
sudo chmod 777 -R var/;
sudo chmod 777 -R media/;
```

Comment: Opa, Rafael Corrêa Gomes.

Obrigado pela contribuição, porem,  eu não gostaria que acontecesse uma intervenção manual. Pois, em testes paralelos fiz por ssh a mudanças das permissões e como seu exemplos. Está tudo OK.

Porem, o que eu estou ( estava ) tentando fazer era conseguir automatizar todo o processo. Sendo que já tem VMs prontas para essa utilização. Estou buscando conhecer melhor no faça eu mesmo.